# How to I override a Java varargs method in Scala?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scala-java-interop

I have a method defined in Java like:

```
void foo(int x, Thing... things)
```

I need to override that in Scala, but both of these give errors:

```
override def foo(x: Int, things: Thing*)
override def foo(x: Int, things: Array[Thing])
```

The errors refer to `<repeated...>` but I don't know what that is.

**Update**

Ugg... nevermind.  I'm in 2.10.0, and I had mis-typed something and didn't have a method body. Then I got confused by this error message, which still seems a odd to me.  In SBT:

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to [...]/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] [...]/src/main/scala/Translator.scala:41: class MyMethodVisitor needs to be abstract, since method visitTableSwitchInsn is not defined
[error] (Note that org.objectweb.asm.Label* does not match <repeated...>[org.objectweb.asm.Label])
[error]   class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor (Opcodes.ASM4) {
[error]         ^
```

The problem is that my `visitTableSwitchInsn` simply lacks a body, but the error suggests that the problem is the type of the varargs parameter.

Comment: This looks like you may be seeing [a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4729) that was fixed in 2.10. If you think not, can you give your version number and a little more context?

Comment: Thanks. I was seeing a bug in my brain, plus a confusing error message (which I've added to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java:

```
package rrs.scribble;

public
class   VA1
{
    public int va1(int... ints) {
        return ints.length;
    }
}
```

Scala:

```
package rrs.scribble

class   VA1S
extends VA1
{
  override
  def va1(ints: Int*): Int =
    ints.length * 2
}
```

SBT:

```
> ~compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to …/scribble/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 15, 2013 3:48:14 PM
1. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
```

This is Scala 2.10, which is consistent with @TravisBrown's comment.

Comment: Thanks.  When I returned after a break, I saw my obvious code mistake. :| My method simply lacked a body. Maybe the error message could be better. I updated the question.